# Connect to Oracle Database inside docker container residing on Oracle VirtualBox Xubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, docker

I have the following setup:

Windows 10 Pro Host with VirtualBox installed.

On VirtualBox I have installed Xubuntu OS.

On Xubuntu OS I have installed docker and setup an Oracle19c database container.
I have enabled a second Host-Only-Adapter in Virtual box and can access my VM from Windows host via SSH.

I wish to know how I can connect to the database inside the Oracle container from Windows Host with SQL Developer or other client?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you start the container you give a `-p hostport:containerport` argument to bind container ports to host ports (for instance, if the same: `-p 1521:1521`).

You can check which ports the host is listening to with:

```
netstat -ltp --numeric-ports
```

or

```
ss -nlt
```

(you'll find that this only reports the ports on IPv6 but AFAIK this has no impact).

Then Windows apps can connect to the DB server in the container by connecting to the port on your VM that you have bound to the container (1521 in this case).